# JQuery UI autocomplete with AJAX post-method not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've already read lots of answers about JQuery UI autocomplete, but it didn't help me to understand why my code won't work. I desperately need it to work, so here's the last version of the code:

```js
$(function (){
   $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({ 
      source: function () {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"autocomplete_backend.py",
         data: {t: $("#autocomplete").val().toLowerCase()},
         success: function(data){
            var ndata = JSON.parse(data);
            response(ndata);
            },
         });
      },
      minLength: 2 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The python script returns a string that contains an array: `["cardiac", "heart", "hearth"]`

Since i suspect, that the problem has something to do with the data format:
`typeof(data)` returns `string`, 
`typeof(ndata)` returns `object`
What am I doing wrong? Thanks already!

Comment: did you try serializing the array server side before sending?

Comment: i'm going to try it. thanks

Comment: What actually happens? Do you see errors? Anything on the dev console? Does the AJAX call happen?

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI? jQuery alone (as you have shown) is not enough.